# Displaying X11/Xorg settings to check if they have been set correctly

Tags: xorg

I used to use Xfce exclusively and am now using xmonad, which I love.
However, now I need to set some things myself.
Like font aliasing and hinting, etc.
Xfce stores font settings in ~/.config/xfce4/Xft.xrdb
I have copied these settings into ~/.Xdefaults

I don't see any real change, though, so I'd like to see if the settings were set.

Is this possible? If so, how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
xrdb -query
```

with an optional grep was the solution.

In my case, the case of Xft settings:

```
xrdb -query | grep Xft
```

Answer (score 3):

Look at

```
/var/log/Xorg.0.log
```

This file should contain all the information from the last X startup. It is ~300 lines on my system at least, but if you have a phrase to search for it should not be a problem.

You could also start with Xfce, save the log file and compare it with the xmonad invocation.